# 这个型体脚板是射出不喷漆的，脚板模具就是砂面的 Help with Translation

Tags: translation

> 这个型体脚板是射出不喷漆的，脚板模具就是砂面的

My doubt here are two phrases:

"The temples of this model

> do not reflect the spray paint

, the molds of the temples

> have the sand surface

Would be grateful if you could correct me whether I am right or wrong here.

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More context would clarify this, but they are probably talking about about die casting, 压铸，模铸

这个型体脚板是射出不喷漆的，
This type of foot plate is not spray painted,
脚板模具就是砂面的
(because) the base (of the) mold is a sand surface.

Comment: The context is about spectacles parts: frontal and temples. 意思是眼镜的部分，眼镜有脚丝（这里是脚板）有前框（frontal).